# How to read each txt, convert it into image, and save them in different images?

Tags: numpy, opencv, operating-system, glob

I would like to let my code read my txt file one by one, convert it into image, and save it with different image, i.e 300s, 600s, 900s,....

I made the code down and it says only the path but did not proceed with its next code.

Could you give me some advice or find the missing or mistaken part of my codes?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import cv2
import os


path = './Master_thesis/Code/dnn_simulation_result/'
interval = 300

folders = []

#r=root, d=dirctories, f=files

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    if not d:
        folders.append(r)

for f in folders:
    print(r)


def txt2image(folders, skiprows) :    

    for folder_name in folders:

        IsFile=(glob.glob(folder_name+"/*.*"))

        for file in IsFile:

            myArray  = np.loadtxt(path, skiprows = skiprows)

            # Set the nodata values to nan
            myArray[myArray == -9999] = np.nan

            # PRISM data is stored as an integer but scaled by 100
            myArray *= 1

            # Plot PRISM array again
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            ax.set_title('Flood area')

            # Get the img object in order to pass it to the colorbar function
            img_plot = ax.imshow(myArray, cmap='jet')

            # Place a colorbar next to the map
            cbar = fig.colorbar(img_plot)

            ax.grid(True)
            plt.show()        

            txt2image = cv2.imwrite('D:/Master_thesis/Code/dnn_simulation_result/dnn_simulation_result/{}.jpg', img_plot)

        return txt2image

txt2image(folders, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: You are doing `np.loadtxt` always on `path`, which is constant. Shouldn't it be `file` instead of `path`?

Comment: true!  I will try this on

Comment: well it is not working